# How to set full Screen size to Android WebView in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-webview

[How to set full Screen size to Android WebView in Unity I want to open it full size and I don't know how it would be done?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3hl0.jpg)

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Are you sure you are using that language? Note that `unity-container` has absolutely no relationship with `unity3d` .. and just because you happen to use a certain IDE (visual studio) doesn't mean your question is about that IDE in specific .. please read tag descriptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A frame is a combination of an origin (where it should be) and a size (how large it should be).

The coordinate system used in UniWebView is top-left based. The zero point (0, 0) in the coordinate is the most top-left point of your screen. And the size is defined by Unity Screen, with Screen.width and Screen.height as its max:
[image]

In this coordinate system, you could set the position and size of the web view quite easy:

```
webView.Frame = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
```